# Which Tory MPs have called for Dominic Cummings' resignation?

Tags: united-kingdom, conservative-party, scandal

The BBC is [reporting](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-52806086) that over 35 Conservative MPs have now called on Boris Johnson's chief adviser, Dominic Cummings, to resign after his Monday statement defending his travel to Durham during the early weeks of the UK coronavirus lockdown:

> The drip drip of Conservative MPs calling on Dominic Cummings to go
>   has continued on Tuesday.
>
> Now surpassing 35, it is getting close to around 10% of the parliamentary party.

The article, however, doesn't provide the names of these MPs - only four are mentioned in the article:

> Junior minister Douglas Ross has resigned after Dominic Cummings'
>   defence of his trip to County Durham during the coronavirus lockdown.
>
> [...]
>
> William Wragg, Conservative MP for Hazel Grove, said it was
>   "humiliating and degrading" to see ministers defending Mr Cummings.
>
> Veteran Tory MP Sir Roger Gale told the BBC the adviser had "sent out
>   a very damaging and dangerous message" to the public.
>
> And Mark Harper, a former Conservative chief whip, said in a statement
>   posted on Twitter that Mr Cummings "should have offered to resign, and
>   the prime minister should have accepted his resignation".

Is there a full list of Conservative MPs who have called on Cummings to resign, or on Boris Johnson to sack him?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The PoliticsHome website is maintaining a list](https://www.politicshome.com/news/article/at-a-glance-every-conservative-mp-that-has-condemned-dominic-cummings) of Conservative MPs who have "condemned" Dominic Cummings. At the time of writing, it lists more than 40 who have said Cummings's position is untenable, he should resign or the PM should sack him.

[The conservativehome webite is also maintaining a list](https://www.conservativehome.com/parliament/2020/05/rolling-list-of-conservative-mps-whove-called-on-cummings-to-go.html). At the time of writing, it lists 39 MPs.

The Telegraph website published an article this afternoon ([paywall](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/politics/2020/05/26/dominic-cummings-latest-news-coronavirus-uk-lockdown-boris-johnson/)) that says "Nearly 40 Conservative MPs, and one minister, have gone public with their concern about Mr Cummings actions and called for him to resign".

Older articles list fewer MPs.